# How change date field to pt-BR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I need to change Date Field to pt-BR

Not do anything because in the documentation don't have examples for this

Comment: If you haven't done anything, I'm not sure how you can reasonably expect any of us to do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

this -> https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/343#issuecomment-457953132
solved my question

> Just add the next to bottom file
>   `resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php`:
>
> ```
> <!-- Change language default -->
> <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr@4.5.2/dist/l10n/es.js"></script>
> <script>
>     flatpickr.localize(flatpickr.l10ns.es)
>     flatpickr('.flatpickr-input')
> </script>
> ```
>
> **NOTE:** If you even haven't the file `resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php` you need copy it from
>   `nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

Do ou wanna to change data value from where? Database? 
In model just use this (in this exemple i change the created_at)

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
}
```

Look for mutators in docs.